# D7: How do you get the name of a module?

Tags: 7

I am using **module_list()** to get a list of all modules, but I want the names of the modules, not their machine name. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`system_rebuild_module_data()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_rebuild_module_data/7) function to get a list of all module data in the system:

```
$module_list = system_rebuild_module_data();
```

Each entry in the array returned from that function contains all the details about the module, e.g.:

[image: screenshot]

It's the same function used by the system modules admin page so I think it's safe to assume this is the best way to get this particular data.

Comment: Awesome. This was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
$info = system_get_info('module', 'example_module');
if ($info) {
   // Print human-readable name of the module
   print $info['name'];
} else {
   print t("No such module found.");
}
```